# algorithmic environment: procedure parameters are too long

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, overflow

I am using the algorithmic environment and the parameters of my Function/Procedure are too long and they overflow. I am wondering what is the solution? Can I somehow force it to stay in a single line or make it multiline nicely? I am not sure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
    \caption{Simple greedy visit sequence evaluator for circular remote attribute grammar}\label{alg:crag-visit-sequence-generator}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{\texttt{VISIT\_SEQUENCE\_EVAL}}{$AG, \hat{\mathscr{D}},\mathscr{V}, \mathit{Val} = \texttt{dict()}, \mathit{history} = \texttt{dict()}, \mathit{inCycle} = \texttt{false}$}
\State \Return TODO
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to use `\newline` in the arguments and then repeat the text that you want to skip horizontally using `\phantom`, that allocates the space but does not actually print anything. So the following can be added:

```
\newline\phantom{\textbf{procedure} \texttt{VISIT\_SEQUENCE\_EVAL}(}
```

which means: new line, then whatever space would be needed if you would print

**procedure** VISIT_SEQUENCE_EVAL(

and then the rest of the arguments.

MWE (note that I removed most of the math mode from the arguments because it was not needed):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
    \caption{Simple greedy visit sequence evaluator for circular remote attribute grammar}\label{alg:crag-visit-sequence-generator}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{\texttt{VISIT\_SEQUENCE\_EVAL}}{$AG, \hat{\mathscr{D}},\mathscr{V}$, \textit{Val} = \texttt{dict()}, \textit{history} = \texttt{dict()},\newline\phantom{\textbf{procedure} \texttt{VISIT\_SEQUENCE\_EVAL}(}\textit{inCycle} = \texttt{false}}
\State \Return TODO
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]